# How to perform value check inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So the task is to make a universal Vector class to perform **add** method whatever(str or int) the x,y values are.
So here is the code that i've tried to execute just to check if try,except somehow works inside a class

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __valuecheck__(self):
        try:
            self.x + "a"
        except TypeError:
            return str(self.x)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)

a = Vector(1,"a")
b = Vector("a",2)
c = a.__add__(b)
print(c)
```

The expected output is

```
Vector(1a,a2)
```

I've tried different variants, defining classic function e.g. def valuecheck(), as well tried adding try,except to **add** and **init** method, but none seem to work. Need your help guys, any tip is very appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: what does it output

Comment: The `__add__` method of a class tells python how to add two instances of that class together (i.e. `Vector(1, "a") + Vector("a", 2)`). You should look into [overloading a class's addition operator](Overloading Addition, Subtraction, and Multiplication Operators).

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy the expected output is Vector(1a,a2)

Comment: @b_c thx for the answer, but i can't imagine how it solves the case?

Comment: im not asking for the expected output, an asking for what it outputs right now

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy nothing, can't concatenate int + str

Comment: Do you mean to concatenate if its a number and a string but add if its a number and a number?

Comment: This question has [major XY-problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think before we can start to help in the long run, we actually need to know what you're trying to accomplish here. Your question goes multiple ways without defining a definite question. Is your question about `error-handling`, about `class-structures` or about `variable-types`? Or is the question just "why doesn't my code work"?

Comment: It was more of a comment that you should use `a + b` after implementing the `__add__` method instead of `a.__add__(b)`. I screwed up my link and it's too late to edit the comment so [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507745/overloading-addition-subtraction-and-multiplication-operators) what I _meant_ to link.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer.

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __valuecheck__(self):
        try:
            self.x + "a"
        except TypeError:
            return str(self.x)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)
    def __add__(self, other):
        mvbh = str(self.x), str(self.y) # My Vector Before Hand
        myVector = ''.join(mvbh)

        ovbh = str(other.x), str(other.y) # Other Vector Before Hand
        otherVector = ''.join(ovbh)

        final = "Vector({}, {})".format(myVector, otherVector) # Change this to create a new vector

        print(final)


a = Vector(1,"a")
b = Vector("a",2)
a.__add__(b)
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer! I just pentested it, and changing the code to a = Vector(1,2)
b = Vector("a","b") gives the output Vector(12, ab)

Comment: Is that what you were looking for, or are you looking for prevention against that? If so, just do a few if statements

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __valuecheck__(self):
        try:
            self.x + "a"
        except TypeError:
            return str(self.x)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(str(self.x) + str(other.x), str(self.y) + str(other.y))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)

a = Vector(1,"a")
b = Vector("a",2)
c = a.__add__(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not right because i don't perform value check at all, and if i have 2 figures they end up being strings

Comment: @ChrisPython your question is very ambigious then. Re-edit you question. what are you trying to do

Comment: @ChrisPython What does that even mean? If you're not checking the value, and always expects it to append new values to the end of your `xy`pair, then why not just create them as strings inside of the `__init__` method?

Comment: @HampusLarsson yeah his question is very confusing