# How to use one object attribute automatically whenever the object is called

Tags: python, class, object

Is there a way to do arithmetic on python class objects, and all the operations will be applied to one attribute automatically. For example:

```
>>> x = Struct(__data__ = [100,100])
>>> y = Struct(__data__ = [200,200])
>>> x + y
Struct(__data__ = [300,300])
>>> np.array(x) + np.array(y)
np.array(Struct(__data__ = [300,300]))
>>> x += y
x ==> Struct(__data__ = [300,300])
>>> x[1:] = 50
x ==> Struct(__data__ = [300,50])
```

I want it to perform like a normal number/array, and all the operations apply to `.__data__` automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading Addition, Subtraction, and Multiplication Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507745/overloading-addition-subtraction-and-multiplication-operators)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, and I am currently doing this, just feel there should be an easier way to handle such a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You need to define you *dunder* or *magic* methods`__add__`, `__mul__`, `__eq__` etc for your class.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.