# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'class' and 'int'

Tags: python

I have a problem with an error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Workers' and 'int'`. I know that the message says that `Workers` is not an `int`, but I don't know how to fix it.

What my code should do: create 5 workers that starts of with a life force 100 and my workers names are there current life force. They are suppose to, one at the time, go to the plant and create one unit of product, if they succeed they lose 10 units of life force and are returned to the back of the queue and have to wait there turn. But if an accident occurs they lose 100 units of life force, dies and are removed from the simulation. The simulation should run as long as there are workers alive and at the end print out how many units of products have been produced.

If I remove `class Workers:` and change the first `def` in `class Roads:` to:

```
class Roads:
    def __init__(self):
        self._workers_road = []
        for worker in range(5):
            self._workers_road.append(100)
```

Then it works just fine, but I need the `class Workers:` to in the long run expand my code and breed more workers and append them to the list in `class Roads:`.

```
import random

class Workers:
    def __init__(self):
        self._worker = 100

    def get_worker(self):
        return self._worker

class Products:
    def __init__(self):
        self._product = True

    def get_product(self):
        return self._product

class Roads:
    def __init__(self):
        self._workers_road = []
        for worker in range(5):
            self._workers_road.append(Workers())

    def workers_left(self):
        if len(self._workers_road) == 0:
            return True

class Storage:
    def __init__(self):
        self._product_stock = []

    def add_product(self):
        self._product_stock.append(Products())

    def get_product_stock(self):
        return 'Storage: ' + str(len(self._product_stock))

class Plants:
    def __init__(self):
        self._plant_list = []
        self._plant_storage = Storage()
        self._road = Roads()

    def add_worker(self):
        self._plant_list.append(self._road._workers_road[0])
        self._road._workers_road.pop(0)

    def create_product(self):
        accident = random.randint(1,10)

        if accident < 5:
            self._plant_storage.add_product()
            self._plant_list[0] -= 10
        else:
            self._plant_list[0] -= 100

    def sub_worker(self):
        if self._plant_list[0] <= 0:
            self._plant_list.pop(0)
        else:
            self._road._workers_road.append(self._plant_list[0])
            self._plant_list.pop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Plants()
    while not a._road.workers_left():
        a.add_worker()
        a.create_product()
        a.sub_worker()
    print(a._plant_storage.get_product_stock())
```

This seems like a fairly easy thing to fix but I'm stuck...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading Addition, Subtraction, and Multiplication Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507745/overloading-addition-subtraction-and-multiplication-operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're operating on the wrong object. You might want to change this:

```
self._plant_list[0] -= 10
```

To this:

```
self._plant_list[0]._worker -= 10
```

Same for the other use of `-=` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying subtract integer from worker object

```py
self._plant_list[0]._worker
```