# Cout calls a method with operator <<

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    char sample[] = "something really weird about c++"; 
    cout << sample << " - huh?"; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is simple c++ code that print something on screen, as I'm from python, it seems really weird for me that an object (according various sources 'cout' is object of class ostream) I just wonder how object can output something on screen or do something like statement and function without calling any method, my best guess << is overloaded under the hood and calls a method on it, if I'm right, would you like to make an object that that do something like 'cout' such as multiply some value without calling a method or by overloading <<?

Comment: Same as if you had typed: `cout.operator<<(sample).operator<<(" - huh?");`  The `<<` is just syntactic sugar for a method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also in Python you can overload operators. For example you can implement the special method `__add__` and then call it via `a + b` (see eg  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507745/overloading-addition-subtraction-and-multiplication-operators) for details). In principle the answer wouldn't be that different if your question was about Python instead of C++. Applying an operator is calling a function.

---

This

```
cout << sample;
```

is a short form of writing

```
cout.operator<<(sample);
```

ie it calls a method of `cout` which is a `std::ostream`.

---

You can provide an overload for the output operator for your custom type like this:

```
struct foo {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    // do something with out and f
    // expected is: write contents of f to out
    // possible is: anything
    return out;
}
```

Note that operators are not necessarily members. Some can only be implemented as member tough. More on operator overloading in C++: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

---

For your specific request

> if I'm right, would you like to make an object that that do something like 'cout' such as multiply some value [without calling a method or] by overloading <<?

```
struct multiplier {
    int value = 1;
    multiplier& operator<<(int x) {
        value *= x;
        return *this;
    }
 };

 multiplier m;
 m << 2 << 3 << 7;
 std::cout << m.value; // prints 42
```

However, operator overloading should be used with caution and the principle of least surprise should be kept in mind. In the above example it would be much more natural to overload `operator*=` instead, because thats the operator that is expected to multiply something on the given object.